# How to exclude a package from ios platform in expo react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I have a React Native Expo app that uses the [`react-native-usb-serialport-for-android`](https://github.com/bastengao/react-native-usb-serialport-for-android) package. It works perfectly on Android devices. However, when I attempt to run the same code on the iOS platform, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: The package 'react-native-usb-serialport-for-android' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 

- You have run 'pod install'
- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
```

I tried below solutions but they are not working as expected.

In package.json

```
"expo": {
    "autolinking": {
      "ios": {
        "exclude": [
          "react-native-usb-serialport-for-android"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

In react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
   dependencies: {
      'react-native-usb-serialport-for-android': { platforms: { ios: null } } 
  } 
}
```

Suggest me a workaround to exclude this lib from ios platform while using in android!

Comment: A workaround could be to make an empty iOS native module under that name, and then remove it from your exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this issue is to have separate `file.ios.jsx` and `file.android.jsx` files instead of a single `file.jsx`. Then you can use this library only in the `jsx` file that is compatible with the respective platform.